# A strange situation happens when doing merge sort in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, mergesort

When I am doing my merge sort, I find something strange happens, which I have no idea why. Since I am not so familiar with Kotlin, I don't know if the problem is my logic or the Kotlin syntax. Need help.

Here is the code. This version works.

```
fun runMergeSort(anArray:IntArray,n:Int){
    mergeSort(anArray,0,n-1)
}

fun mergeSort(intArray: IntArray,left:Int,right:Int){
    if(left<right){
        val mid = (left+right)/2
        mergeSort(intArray,left,mid)
        mergeSort(intArray,mid+1,right)
        merge(intArray,left,mid,right)
    }
}

fun merge(intArray:IntArray,left:Int,mid:Int,right:Int){
    val aux = IntArray(right-left+1)
    for(i in left..right){
        aux[i-left] = intArray[i]
    }
    var i = left
    var j = mid+1
    for(k in left..right){
        if(i>mid){
            intArray[k] = aux[j-left]
            j++
        }
        else if (j>right){
            intArray[k] = aux[i-left]
            i++
        }
        else if(aux[i-left]<aux[j-left]){
            intArray[k] = aux[i-left]
            i++
        }
        else{
            intArray[k] = aux[j-left]
            j++
        }
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val anArray = intArrayOf(7,5,2,5,11,3,6,8)
    runMergeSort(anArray,anArray.size)
    for(i in anArray)
        print("$i ")
}
```

However, when I change the function mergeSort to below

```
fun mergeSort(intArray: IntArray,left:Int,right:Int){
    if(right>=left)
        return
    val mid = (left+right)/2
    mergeSort(intArray,left,mid)
    mergeSort(intArray,mid+1,right)
    merge(intArray,left,mid,right)
}
```

I can't sort the array. Don't know what to do about this...

Answer (score 3):

The equivalent to

```
if (left < right) {
    /* do something */
}
```

is

```
if (left >= right) 
    return
/* do something */
```

In your sample that doesn't work you use `right >= left`. Change it to `left >= right`.